# Should Instrumentation data such as metrics, be transmitted over HTTPS?

Tags: http, optimization, https, metrics, micrometer

Should information such as metrics generated from an application that are devoid of any business information, still be subject to encryption/decryption over HTTPS, when being transmitted within the eco system of an organization, that sits behind firewalls?
The reason I am asking this question is that, since the metrics data does not give away any business information, and is behind a firewall already, beyond everything, since the data is tremendous in size (time-series data in the counts of millions of records per second), does it make sense to reduce the computational complexity involved in using HTTPS, that forces encryption/decryption at every hop of the metrics' journey from source to destination, by redirecting metrics data with an ingress policy applied, that routes the packets via another port such as 8080 to skip encryption/decryption, thus saving us BIG on resource utilization, and of course reduced time complexity?
Or is it a known compromise that can in some way turn into a vulnerability hole, that can lead to breaches in the system?

Context:

- The applications being monitored are communicating over HTTPS.
- The metrics scraping agents are asked to communicate over HTTP
- Ingress policy applied on the application node, recognizes the calls from the known metrics scraping agent and routes the packets via a non HTTPS port such as 8080, in order to skip the certificate validation plus mainly, the decryption of metrics payload in the request coming in.

I am looking for suggestions and inputs, especially from someone who has had this problem to solve in their experience. Anybody else with relevant information is more than welcome to add to it.

Any leads appreciated.
Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> the metrics data does not give away any business information

I think this is not true. Metrics can record traffic patterns also in a business context (e.g.: what users searched for/bought the most, etc.).

Also, it can accidentally contain sensitive information (it should not but accidents can happen). Additionally, it can help attackers to get more data about:

- Your infrastructure (what platforms you use)
- Your environment (os, java version, etc.)
- Your app topology (who calls who)

Please check the [Fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing):

> #4 The network is secure

Being behind a firewall does not mean attackers can't get in, that's one of the reasons why you use HTTPS on the internal network.